# assign to int[][4] in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I assign to a multi dimensional array without casting [][] to **? I have an example below. What I found was [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) but that uses `int**` rather then `new int[][4]`.

```
#include<cassert>

int a[8][4];
int*b = &a[0][0];
int*c = &a[2][0];
int*d = &a[0][2];

int main() {
    //shows right side is closer
    assert(d-b==2);
    assert(c-b==8); 
    auto aa = new int[][4];
    //set the right side, but is a syntax error
    //aa[][0] = new int[8];
    //type error
    aa[0] = new int[8];
}
```

Comment: use `vector<vector<int>>` and save yourself a heap of potential problems...

Comment: @MatsPetersson *"a heap of potential problems"* pun intended

Comment: not to be 'smart', but when was `new` introduced into C?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I'm too lazy to write the malloc equivalent

Comment: "Assign to an array"? Arrays in C++ are not assignable.

Comment: @AndreyT: So is `int*var[size]` my only option? why the heck is `int var[][size]` legal!?!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: This isn't for using. I noticed `int var[][size]` is legal and couldn't figure out how to assign to it

Comment: @KevinDTimm have you never heard about the C/C++ language? Its the language developed by the C programmers who have access to a C++ compiler.

Comment: @KevinDTimm its characterized by the use of `new/delete`as if they were lollipops, and the use of `strlen()` instead of `std::string`, and other C-reinvent-the-weel-every-minute features

Comment: @acidzombie24 `int var[][size]` isn't legal.  You're just using a broken compiler.  You must specify the size of _all_ of the dimensions in a new expression.  Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know how many bytes to request.

Comment: @acidzombie24: What your options are depends on what you are trying to do. At this point it is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @AndreyT: it's been answered. I was trying to understand why `int[][4]` exist and it happens to be illegal (although my compiler doesnt give me an error as clang/gcc does) and is used for typecast/function params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting an error on the line with the `new
int[][4]`.  There must be an expression inside the `[]`.
Otherwise, how can the compiler know how much to allocate.
(Some quick checks with VC++, which erroneously does accept this
expression, shows that it treats it as the equivalent of `new
int[0][4]`, and allocates 0 bytes.  It doesn't compile with
g++.)

And of course, you confuse things additionally by abusing
`auto`.  The one reason *never* to use `auto` is that you don't
know the actual type, and `auto` means you don't have to know it
(until you want to use the variable, of course).  In this case,
you should definitely not use `auto`, because the type is a bit
special, and you want your readers to know it:

```
int (*aa)[4] = new int[8][4];
```

Once you see this, it should be obvious that `aa[0]` has type
`int[4]`, and there's no way you can assign a pointer to it,
since it isn't a pointer.

Of course, in C++, you'd never write anything like this anyway.
You'd define a `Matrix2D` class, and use it.  (And it would
probably use a `std::vector<int>` to get the memory, and
calculate the single index from the two you give.  Internally,
of course, so you don't have to think about it.)  There is, in
fact, *never* a case for using array `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int (*array)[4] = (int (*)[4])malloc(sizeof(int) * 8 * 4);
```

now you can access up to

```
array[7][3];
```

Comment: I rather use `int *var[4]; var[0]=new int[10];` instead

Comment: @acidzombie24 then you are in the `int **` scenario, I thought you wanted to avoid that. And you would need to do 4 allocations. `int ** != int (*)[4]`

Comment: Its more to learn how to use that syntax or why it exist. Normally i use vector or if i must (in C) malloc(sizeof(int)*width*height*dim3*dim4). +1 anyways cause i did say that

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/18723991/598940 indicates `a = new int[][8]` is actually not legal.

From your comments, are you asking why `a = new int[][8]` is legal but `a[][4]` is not?

`int[]` is a type expression representing the same as the type `int*`. It exists (I believe) to allow for more descriptive type declarations (perhaps among other things)

```
void foo(int* x);   // is x an array of ints? or just a pointer to a single one?
void foo(int[] x);  // ah, ok -- x is intended to represent an array of ints
```

The value expression `a[]`, on the other hand, has no meaning.

Comment: `a = new int[][8]` _isn't_ legal.  The only place in C where something like `int [][8]` would be legal is as a function parameter.